# Get Max(Amount) and associated Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have the following query which returns the correct values, but I also need to get the associated Income Type for that row. What is the best way of getting this, and if there were other fields in the table also, how could I get those as well?

```
select 
    PersonID,
    max(Amount)
from #Temp
group by
    PersonID
```

Sample Data:

```
Create Table #Temp
(
    ID int,
    PersonID int,
    IncomeType varchar(50),
    Amount money
)

insert into #Temp
(
    ID,
    PersonID,
    IncomeType,
    Amount
)
select
    1,
    1,
    'IncomeType1',
    50
union all
select
    2,
    1,
    'IncomeType2',
    35
union all
select
    3,
    1,
    'IncomeType3',
    75
union all
select
    4,
    1,
    'IncomeType4',
    17
union all
select
    5,
    2,
    'IncomeType1',
    100
union all
select
    6,
    2,
    'IncomeType2',
    76
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the most efficient method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from #Temp t
where t.Amount = (select max(t2.amount) from t t2 where t2.PersonId = t.PersonID);
```

This matches the amount to the maximum amount for each person and only returns the rows where they match.

This is usually more efficient than the canonical approach using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from #temp t
     ) t
where t.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I do not understand this answer. Can you add a simple table to elaborate? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID, PersonID, IncomeType, Amount
FROM #Temp
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Amount DESC);
```